# thymeleaf images not loading even though i added files in static folder and also by normally doing it in template folder?

Tags: thymeleaf

### Not able to load images in while using the thymeleaf

```
<img  th:src= "@{/images/admingimage.png}"  src=""alt="admingimages"/>
```

[image: images folder in static folder]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I added this path in the springsecurity.java file

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.requestMatchers("/register/**","/", "/home", "/index", "/register", "../static/css", "../static/images").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/index").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/users").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers("/homepage").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/aboutus").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/rtoServices").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/userlogin").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/static").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/images").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/static/images/").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/static/images/*").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/static/css/*").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/static/css/").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/static/css/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/home", "/index", "/register", "../static/css", "../static/images").permitAll())
```

[image: springsecurity.java file]

> It worked for me after adding all this paths to the springsecurity.java

[image]

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).